# Convert Binary data from file to readable string

Tags: c#-4.0

I have binary data stored in a file. I am doing this:

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\carlist.dat");
string ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileBytes);
```

This is giving me following result with lot of invalid characters. What am i doing wrong?

?D{F ?x@??4????? NBR-OF-CARSNUMBER-OF-CARS!"#??? NBR-OF-CARS$%??1y0#123?G??#$ NBR-OF-CARS%45??1y#  NUMBER-OF-CARSd?

Comment: Those '?' are due to bytes that are outside of the valid ASCII range. What result are you expecting?

Comment: Also, have a look at [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to better understand text encoding.

Answer (score 0):

hmm... seems like a save was made from a byte buffer where after NBR-OF-CARS was written some numeric data. If you have an access to the code that saves the file could you check if there are numbers over there and if there are - check does the code converts numbers to string before witing the value into the binary stream.

Comment: I think data was compressed before saving.